How to set SetParent in WPF on .NET 8?
I want to set a SetParent in my WPF application, but when I try to do that, it doesn't work. I try it in .NET 8.
The program where I want to set the parent is calc.exe.
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = Process.Start("calc.exe");

    // Find the handle of the external window
    IntPtr externalWindowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;

    if (externalWindowHandle != null)
    {
        // Reparent the external window into the WPF application
        SetParent(externalWindowHandle, new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("External window not found.");
    }
}

I am expecting the view of calc.exe to appear inside my WPF view.

No, that doesn't work. SetParent works for windows of the same process only.

@PMF The documentation doesn't say the handles have to belong to the same process. In the section about DPI-awareness, it implies that the call can be cross-process.

The process' main window handle may not be immediately available. You should block until it's ready:
Process process = Process.Start("calc.exe");

// Wait until the process finishes creating the window handle
process.WaitForInputIdle();

// Find the handle of the external window
IntPtr externalWindowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;


l try it but doesn't work. the calc.exe doesn't appear inside my wpf view

@casisa It appears that calc.exe on Windows 10/11 just launches the UWP calculator app and then immediately exits. This would work on older versions of Windows.

On Windows 11 (23H2) it does NOT immediately exit.

To show that this technique works for non-UWP apps, try replacing calc.exe with dialer.exe.

with dialer.exe Works, l don,'t understand why whit UWP apps doesn't work.

@casisa Because Microsoft does things without any regard to the impact of their actions.
